# What is the relationship between Angular JavaScript and TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I am very new into web design and applications. I know Angular JavaScript is a "JS framework" that extends HTML attributes. TypeScript is a "superset" of JS which allows static representation of JS dynamic type system. I wonder what is the relationship between these two? Can they be used together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Angular JavaScript and TypeScript?

TypeScript is just a language that transpiles to JavaScript.

You can use either with AngularJS.

## More

more about typescript : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/why-typescript.html

Comment: AngularJS 2.0 is written in TypeScript also https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2015/03/05/angular-2-built-on-typescript/

Answer (score 0):

Angular JavaScript is the frame work for front-end web application based on JavaScript maintained by Google, While on the same place Typescript is statically typed programming language designed by Microsoft corporation. Typescript is being used with AngularJS as it can evolve quicker since they're not bound by the ES standard. Successful features that are introduced via Typescript may make it in to core JavaScript over time, so it's a way to influence the standard as well.